# Critical hit with Improved Pact Weapon or things like Hexblade's Curse

Tags: dnd-5e

I play a [Hexblade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#TheHexblade) Pact of the Blade warlock and thought, "Hey, if I throw a natural 20, are my bonuses from Improved Pact Weapon and Hexblade's Curse duplicated?"

(The same applies to bonus damage from my fallen aasimar's necrotic shroud and other bonuses that consist in flat bonus damage rather than in extra dice as the d4 from *bless*.)

As I have searched and couldn't find an answer, I thought about asking by myself.

PS: I know ability modifiers aren't duplicated and extra dice from, *divine smite*, etc are.

Comment: Just want to point out that Bless only adds to attack rolls, not damage rolls, as you seem to suggest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No, you only double damage dice

The rules on what critical hits do are found on page 196 of the PHB (bold added):

> When you score a critical hit, you get to **roll extra dice** for the attack’s damage against the target. **Roll all of the attack’s damage dice twice** and add them together. **Then add any relevant modifiers as normal.** To speed up play, you can roll all the damage dice at once.

Damage done via something other than dice (like adding your Charisma modifier from Hexblade's Curse, or the +1 you would get to damage from the Improved Pact Weapon invocation) is not increased by a critical hit.

Comment: Thanks, my question rised since I didn't understand well if all that extra flat damage was considered a "relevant modifier" as the ability modifier.

Comment: @Zorsal what else could it have been?